# Error while sending XHR from Chrome extension to PHP page

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am unable to send an XHR from a Chrome extension to a PHP page.I am getting the error :

```
   **Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.**
```

This is the error that is being returned by the xmlhttp.responseText (here xmlhttp is the XHR). Can someone please tell me what the problem is?

PS: The PHP page works well when directly loaded in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sending correct data. That error is your server side not accepting correct data. Double check your content type too.